# Facebook Application Template Tutorial - not canvas application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using Facebook Application Template, The template is creating canvas application, and i want a regular one with just Facebook authentication,

if i'm canceling the "App of Facebook" i get an error "Sorry, the application you were using is misconfigured. Please try again later.".

How can i get the Facebook application work with mvc 4.5 template but as regular app and not canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook Application Template is designed as a Canvas application, which is not what you're looking for.

Fortunately, the ASP.NET team built a number of alternative authentication providers into the default ASP.NET Internet Application template.

Fire up VS, and create a new MVC 4 Internet Application project. Open AuthConfig.cs, uncomment the 3 Facebook lines, and paste in your application details (get these from the Facebook developers center).  Now, your application will support both local authentication (username/password) and Facebook Authentication!

For a full tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the ASP.NET Facebook Template is only for Canvas Applications. We are planning to support web applications either with the same template or a new template at a later time. For now, you can see a sample ASP.NET web app here: https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-aspnet-sample. It is a bit dated (MVC3), but it should help you get started.